# If $f(x)$ = $e^x$ + x, what is $f(x+3)$ in terms of $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recursion

As the title suggests, the question is rather simple:

"$f(x)$ = $e^x$ + x. Write $f(x+3)$ in terms of $f(x)$."

I encountered this problem in an precalc textbook, in the chapter regarding functions, and couldn't find the solution anywhere in the book. Although I have made progress in finding a solution (see below), I'm not quite sure if my steps are right, and whether or not my solution is in the simplest form possible.

My logic goes as follows:

$f(x+3) =e^{x+3} + x + 3$

Set f(x) = y.

$y = e^x + x$

$e^x = y - x$

$ln(e^x) = ln(y-x)$

$x = ln(y -x)$

I was able to notice that this is recursive, and got the following:

$x = ln(y - ln(y - ln(y - \dots)))$

Plugging this into our expression for $f(x+3)$, we get:

$f(x+3) = e^3(e^x) + x + 3$

$f(x+3) = e^3(e^{ln(y - ln(y - ln(y - \dots)))}) + ln(y - ln(y - ln(y - \dots))) + 3$

$f(x+3) = e^3(y - ln(y - ln(y - \dots)))) + ln(y - ln(y - ln(y - \dots))) + 3$

$f(x+3) = e^3(f(x) - ln(f(x) - ln(f(x) - \dots)))) + ln(f(x) - ln(f(x) - ln(f(x) - \dots))) + 3$

So, I've gotten to this point, but I'm not sure how to proceed- or whether or not I'd even need to proceed any further. Is a recursive answer like this one acceptable for such a question? If not, how can I try and express $f(x+3)$ in a non-recursive manner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The original question seems a bit ill-posed but does $f(x+3) = e^3 f(x) + (1-e^3)x + 3$ suffice?

Comment: Don't think so- I've seen quite a few of these questions before, and the general gist of it is that you don't want an x remaining in the expression of f(x+3). You only want to express it in terms of f(x).

Comment: If there are limitations that prevent an expression like whpowell96's in place... then what leads you to believe that this should even be possible in the first place?

Comment: @JMoravitz Well, again, I simply mentioned what I think is a correct solution in the question itself: all I'm curious about is whether or not a solution involving recursion would even be accepted in the first place, and where or not there would be a way to write my answer without needing recursion.